# How to split a pandas dataframe based on column prefix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I imported from a csv.  It goes something like this:

```
df
A.1  B.1  A.2  B.2
1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2
```

My question is, what would be an efficient way to turn this into seperate data frames just comprised of A's and B's

```
df_a
A.1  A.2
1    1
2    2

df_b
B.1  B.2
1    1
2    2
```

I am not picky as far as the column names, would be fine with having them just be stripped to 1 and 2 etc but haven't been able to find a good way to do this.  I am also open to other/better ways to accomplish what I am trying to do in case this doesn't make sense to someone more knowledgable.  Thanks!

Comment: You should go with @unutbu's answer, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`df.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with regex patterns:

```
df_a, df_B = df.filter(regex=r'^A'), df.filter(regex=r'^B')
```

or

```
df_a, df_B = df.filter(like='A'), df.filter(like='B')
```

Note that if you use `like='A'` then all columns whose name *contains* `'A'` will be selected. If you use `regex=r'^A'` then only those columns whose name *begins* with an `A` will be selected.

---

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   A.1  B.1  A.2  B.2
0    1    1    1    1
1    2    2    2    2

In [8]: df_a, df_B = df.filter(regex=r'^A'), df.filter(regex=r'^B')

In [9]: df_a
Out[9]: 
   A.1  A.2
0    1    1
1    2    2

In [10]: df_B
Out[10]: 
   B.1  B.2
0    1    1
1    2    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I understand correctly you just need N new dataframes according to their column name.

```
dfa = df[[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("A")]].copy()
# same for dfb, dfc...
```

Note that `copy()` is required if you wish to later apply changes to that new dataframe `dfa`. Otherwise, if I remember correctly, you would be applying changes by pointer, much like when using dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

To select the columns:

```
dfa = df[['A.1', 'A.2']]
```

To change the name of the columns:

```
dfa.reindex=["a1","a2"]
```